# Using JavaScript to do ASP.NET postback (clicking LinkButton) - postback occurs but not Click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, pagerequestmanager

I am using some script to cause a postback. Here is the context:

- User clicks link to perform a function that needs to know their current location
- Script gets current location from browser (using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition)
- When it has the location (the above call is asynchronous - you have to wait for the user to consent to share their location) I want the script to post the location back to the server. I do this by simulating a postback from a hidden link button.

Here is the relevant code:

```
function submitLocation_Inline(position) {
var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
document.getElementById("ctr11837_Locator_hLat").value = latitude;
document.getElementById("ctr11837_Locator_hLng").value = longitude;
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm._doPostBack('ctr11837_Locator_btnSubmitLocation', 'inline');
} 

<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctr11837$Locator$btnSubmitLocation','')" id="ctr11837_Locator_btnSubmitLocation"></a>
```

In the code behind I have a handler for the click event on the hidden linkbutton (btnSubmitLocation_Click). However this is never called. The postback does happen fine, but to process it I have to examine the Request["_*EVENTTARGET"] and Request["*_EVENTARGUMENT"] during Page_Load to verify it is the postback I want.

How would I adapt my code to cause the btnSubmitLocation_Click to be called?

PS - not sure if this is relevant: the hidden linkbutton is inside an UpdatePanel.

Comment: checking the `__EventTarget` hidden field and firing the click handler manually is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are calling __doPostback() sending the ClientId of the control (I suppose you are using an asp.net link button). Just take a look to the `href` automatically generated by the linkbutton.

Try calling `prm.__doPostBack('ctr11837$Locator$btnSubmitLocation', 'inline')` instead.

EDIT: And it looks like you dropped a underscore in `prm.__doPostBack()`, check your code.

Comment: Thanks - this turns out to be 90% right so accepting the answer. You need to use the "unique ID with dollars" in the call to __doPostBack (the function with a double underscore - as seen in all automatically generated postback calls). The only thing not quite right was that calling prm.__doPostBack() doesn't work - you have to just call __doPostBack(). There is however a prm._doPostBack() function (with a single underscore) which I was using before.